# Why activities button and sidebar overlap?

Tags: gnome-shell, 19.10, ubuntu-dock

In a fresh 19.10 install (hDPI) the activities button and the sidebar overlap as shown in this picture:

[image: detail]

Same in 100% scale.

how can I fix it?

[image]

Comment: Did you 0bserve it specifically on hDPI?? In my Ubuntu 19.10 I didn't see overlap.

Comment: Is it possible to attach the full screen - screenshot?